# Get displayed string for cell value with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using `openpyxl` to deal with `excel` .xlsx files. Some of the columns in the files contain cells of different number types. I can get the number_type and value from the Cell object, but *cannot find an easy way to get a* ***string***. I've take a few hours on the docs and sources of openpyxl but found nothing.

For example, I get this output from ipython:

```
In [6]: ws['D4'].value
Out[6]: 0.02

In [7]: ws['D4'].data_type
Out[7]: 'n'

In [8]: ws['D4'].number_format
Out[8]: '0.0%'

In [9]: ws['D2'].number_format
Out[9]: u'yyyy"\u5e74"m"\u6708"d"\u65e5";@'

In [10]: ws['D2'].value
Out[10]: 42370L
```

How can I get a string like `'2%'` and `u'2016\u5e741\u67081\u65e5'`? The cells may be of some custom cell formats so I prefer a general way.

Comment: What have you done finally ?

Comment: @keepAlive I switched to `.csv` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of any cell is the Python equivalent of the Excel type. openpyxl is a library for the file format and not an application like Excel. Therefore, it only supports the ability to set and read number formats but not apply them. That said, you could easily write your own function to do what you want (create a printf type format) based on the specification.

Comment: I see I have to format the data by myself. I found some specs on MSDN like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx). But they are mostly about how to retrieve data from the files and I'm still not sure how to format the data. Am I missing something? Or the details about formatting cell data is out of the scope of these specs?

Comment: I haven't looked at using the format in any detail. We only use number formats for checking whether something is a date or time. Your best bet is to look at the relevant part of the specification §18.8.30. This should allow you to create something suitable in Python.